# Use username password on different subdomain

Tags: users, subsites

I now have a website which is using drupal. This is the 'main' website on the www domain. I would like to build a small gimmick which is only accessible to my users. This gimmick site is probably not using drupal at all.

Is there a way to duplicate the login procedure for my subdomain so that only users from my main site can use the gimmick site?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes,there is no problem using  drupal user table, you just need implement you site and  connect to data base that Drupal install on it and then just need use `user table` ,
only one note remain that the password  saved with `md5` method in  user `table`.
I thing is not complex, the summery of answer is `connect to db` use `uid`(or `name`) and `password` field of `users` table .

**as sample code :**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="drupaldb"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword));

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// want to want
echo "congratulation ,you login";

}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: Would've worked well, but the password row in any drupal is hashed. I think for security reasons.

Comment: yes, it is hashed by `md5` method. md5 hashing is very simple in php/

Comment: @user1111652 ,you should md5 hashing method